# Transparent arrow in between 2 <sections>

Tags: html, css, canvas

How do I make a transparent arrow that is between 2 sections? Both sections have its background-image and with `background-size: cover`.

An example:

[image: Arrow in between 2 sections]

I have been researching for various methods but most I found are usually [making of a transparent arrow across a single image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-arrow-triangle), or making of [CSS triangle](http://www.cssarrowplease.com/), both of which I believe do not work for this case.

[A snippet on what I have so far](http://codepen.io/uzyn/pen/aNggJW). I would be okay even if it's not a pure CSS solution but I cannot find a way to do it reliably with a variable width.

Comment: This may be of help too (written before clipping in CSS was supported in general - older browsers won't): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659926/creating-a-transparent-inner-notch/18664225#18664225

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property in CSS. Support is not wery good, but it works.

```css
section {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.first {
  background: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 85%, 60% 85%, 50% 100%, 40% 85%, 0 85%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 85%, 60% 85%, 50% 100%, 40% 85%, 0 85%);
}

.second {
  background: green;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="first"></section>
<section class="second"></section>
```

Another woy would be to use SVG element for cliping background image. Also look into another question: [Transparent arrow/triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-arrow-triangle?lq=1)

Comment: That works very well! Thanks!